# Is it useful to create many threads for a specific process to increase the chance of this process executed?

Tags: process, operating-system

This is an interview question I encountered today. I have some knowledge about OS but not really proficient at it. I think maybe there are limited threads for each process can create?
Any ideas will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be viewed [at least] in two ways:

1. Can your process get more CPU time by creating many threads that need to be scheduled?

or

2. Can your process get more CPU time by creating threads to allow processing to continue when another thread(s) is blocked?

The answer to #1 is largely system dependent. However, any rationally-designed system is going to protect again rogue processes trying this. Generally, the answer here is NO. In fact, some older systems only schedule processes; not threads. In those cases, the answer is always NO.

The answer to #2 is generally YES. One of the reasons to use threads is to allow a process to continue processing while it has to wait on some external event.

Answer (score 1):

- The number of threads that can run in parallel depends on the number of CPUs on your machine
- It also depends on the characteristic of the processes you're running, if they're consuming CPU - it won't be efficient to run more threads than the number of CPUs on your machine, on the other hand, if they do a lot of I/O, or any other kind of tasks that blocks a lot - it would make sense to increase the number of threads.
- As for the question "how many" - you'll have to tune your app, make measurements and decide based on actual data.

Comment: Thank u first! I get it.    And,  if Process A has 100 threads and Process B only has 10 threads, and OS schedule threads execution not the process, so can I say Process A has an advantage over Process B?

Comment: @FredXue if this answer solve your problem and go ahead and accept the answer by clicking tick sign

Comment: @FredXue not necessarily: The OS schedules CPU time per process, each process manages the scheduling of its own threads. By creating a big number of threads (say 100 - like in your example) you might be shooting yourself in the foot because the process will waste many CPU cycles on context-switching between the threads instead of doing any *actual* work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Depends on the OS.

I'd say it depends on how the OS scheduler is implemented.
From personal experience with my hobby OS, it can certainly happen.

In my case, the scheduler is implemented with a round robin algorithm, per thread, independent on what process they belong to.

So, if process A has 1 thread, and process B has 2 threads, and they are all busy, Process B would be getting 2/3 of the CPU time.

There are certainly a variety of approaches. Check [Scheduling_(computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))

Throw in priority levels per process and per thread, and it really depends on the OS.